# How to add values from checkbox to database

Tags: php

Let me start by saying that I googled this and tried different things, but I'm still stuck and need some help as this is my first time trying out checkboxes with php...
I have a section in my HTML file as follows

```
<label class="labelStyle" for="text">XXX:</label>
                        <div class="checkboxAlign">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="XX[]" value="Apple">Apple<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="XX[]" value="Orange">Orange<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="XX[]" value="Strawberry">Strawberry<br>
                        </div>
```

But I am having trouble with the PHP part of it as it's not adding the checked items to my database.

Try this

```
if (!empty($_POST['XX']))
{
    foreach($_POST['XX'] as $check)
    {
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table
            id = (
                SELECT id
                FROM yy
                WHERE xx = ?)"))){  
            echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }
         if(!($stmt->bind_param("s",  $_POST['XX'])))    { 
        echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    }
}
```

I know the issue is within this php snippet, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `WHERE FoodTriggerItem = ?` is the syntax

Comment: @colburton I tried that too

Comment: @rose Try my answer

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar Thanks! Still doesn't work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (!empty($_POST['XX']))
{
    foreach($_POST['XX'] as $check)
    {
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table
            id = (
                SELECT id
                FROM yy
                WHERE xx = ?)"))){  //added ? in place of $check
            echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }
        if(!($stmt->bind_param("s", $check)))    { // added $check in place of $_POST['XX']
            echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this works! I just forgot to add something earlier... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if(!($stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['FoodTriggerItem'])))    {
                    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                }
```

TO

```
if(!($stmt->bind_param("s", $check)))    {
                    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                }
```